# How to separate the dataframe matching keywords anywhere in the rows into two dataframes

Tags: regex, r, sorting

I have this dataframe called `mydf` where I have sample rows that starts with `GS0000XXXX-ASM` which has two parts `high confidence` data and `low confidence` data. I want to separate the high and low confidence data for each sample row and get the result as shown below.

```
mydf<-structure(list(assembly_id = c("GS000038075-ASM", "High confidence t(2:Y), t(5:7)", 
NA, "Low confidence t(2:Y), t(5:7)", NA, NA, "GS000038040-ASM", 
"High confidence t(1:17), t(2:6)", NA, "Low confidence t(1:17), t(2:6)", 
NA, NA), sample_id = c("GS02589-DNA_E06", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"GS02589-DNA_F01", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), customer_sample_id = c("AMLM12001KP", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1114002", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `>Id` = c(NA, 
"4264", NA, "217", "4264", "219", NA, "3329", "3764", "790", 
"1586", "3329"), LeftChr = c(NA, "chr2", NA, "chr2", "chr2", 
"chr2", NA, "chr1", "chr2", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1"), LeftPosition = c(NA, 
"133017438", NA, "133012293", "133017438", "133018715", NA, "207868617", 
"156528197", "91852788", "91852976", "207868617")), .Names = c("assembly_id", 
"sample_id", "customer_sample_id", ">Id", "LeftChr", "LeftPosition"
), row.names = c(1L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 17L, 19L, 20L, 22L, 
23L, 24L), class = "data.frame")
```

result

```
result <- structure(list(assembly_id = c("GS000038075-ASM", "High confidence t(2:Y), t(5:7)", 
NA, "GS000038040-ASM", "High confidence t(1:17), t(2:6)", NA, 
"GS000038075-ASM", "Low confidence t(2:Y), t(5:7)", NA, NA, "GS000038040-ASM", 
"Low confidence t(1:17), t(2:6)", NA, NA), sample_id = c("GS02589-DNA_E06", 
NA, NA, "GS02589-DNA_F01", NA, NA, "GS02589-DNA_E06", NA, NA, 
NA, "GS02589-DNA_F01", NA, NA, NA), customer_sample_id = c("AMLM12001KP", 
NA, NA, "1114002", NA, NA, "AMLM12001KP", NA, NA, NA, "1114002", 
NA, NA, NA), `>Id` = c(NA, "4264", NA, NA, "3329", "3764", NA, 
"217", "4264", "219", NA, "790", "1586", "3329"), LeftChr = c(NA, 
"chr2", NA, NA, "chr1", "chr2", NA, "chr2", "chr2", "chr2", NA, 
"chr1", "chr1", "chr1"), LeftPosition = c(NA, "133017438", NA, 
NA, "207868617", "156528197", NA, "133012293", "133017438", "133018715", 
NA, "91852788", "91852976", "207868617")), .Names = c("assembly_id", 
"sample_id", "customer_sample_id", ">Id", "LeftChr", "LeftPosition"
), row.names = c("1", "3", "5", "17", "19", "20", "1.1", "6", 
"7", "8", "17.1", "22", "23", "24"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Why do you want to replicate the rows?

Comment: @akrun because the each GS0000----ASM row has one set of high confidence and low confidence data. So basically i need to separate the high confidence and low confidence data for each sample row. There are 100s of such sample rows.

Comment: You can try `do.call(rbind,lapply(split(mydf, cumsum(!is.na(mydf$sample_id))), function(x) {gr1 <- cumsum(!is.na(x[-1, 'assembly_id'])); do.call(rbind, lapply(split(x[-1,], gr1), function(y) rbind(x[1,], y)))}))` and then if you need to order `High` vs `Low` use `grepl`

Comment: I've clicked through a good portion of your questions, and _zero_ of them contained any of your coding attempts. this is not your personal code-writing service, please share your attempts and show minimal effort

Comment: @akrun Thank you, this is very helpful. Could you please put it in answer below with some comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We `split` the dataset into a `list` by grouping based on non-NA values in the 'sample_id' column.

```
lst <- split(mydf, cumsum(!is.na(mydf$sample_id)))
```

Then, loop through the `list`,  create another grouping variable (can be done in the first step itself, but for clarity), with non-NA values of 'assembly_id' , `split` the `list` elements  and `rbind` the first row in each of the `list` elements, collapse the list of lists with `do.call(rbind`, and finally, we `rbind` all the `list` elements together.

```
lst1 <- lapply(lst, function(x){
          gr1 <- cumsum(!is.na(x[-1, 'assembly_id']))
          do.call(rbind, 
            lapply(split(x[-1,], gr1), 
                 function(y) rbind(x[1,], y)))})

res <- do.call(rbind, lst1)
row.names(res) <- NULL
```